TestSigma UI Test Automation Crashes on a Flutter Web App
I have captured user Test Case using TestSigma on a Flutter web app running on Windows Chrome (chrome version 114) and it records user inputs just fine.
However re-running or simulating the sequence crashes where user entered text in a Text field. The error says:
  Test Data
    "bw0000000"

    Error code
    1020200

    Element
    inputTag8

    Error Message
    Element with locator"XPATH://div[@id='loader-content']/following-sibling::flutter-view[contains(normalize-space(),"flutter-view flt-scene-host { font: normal normal 14px sans-serif;}flutter-view flt-semantics input[type=range] { appearance: none; -webkit-appearance: none; width: 100%; position: absolute; border: n")]//input[contains(@class, 'flt-text-editing') and contains(@class, 'transparentTextEditing')]" not found in current page.
Please visit below page for more details

It looks like Testsigma cannot identify the web elements including textfield, which is what i  expected, but not to crash as Testsigma can use a temporary element name
Anyone knows what to do? I need to automate user inputs using json files so as to confirm correct working of the web app in validating different inputs.
Chrome was downgraded to v114 for testgigma
I bypassed SSL certificates for the test web site so as to run posts methods which works fine outside testing.
I tried K6 app for automation and it gives a similar problem.


Be careful with the usage of quotation marks. For your case, use single quotation inside the Xpath expression It could be the reason it breaks. So, fix this first (normalize-space(),'....')]//input). 2. Try to simplify some parts of your XPath expression. For example : following-sibling::flutter-view[contains(.,'flutter-view flt-scene-host') and contains(.,'flutter-view flt-semantics') and contains(.,'input[type=range]')].

